# How to get website URL in a SharePoint custom masterpage?

Tags: html, sharepoint, master-pages

I'm making a custom masterpage and on the navigation bar, I would like to have a button which goes back to the current site main page. This masterpage will be use for other subsites as well. Is there a way for me to get the current site URL within the index file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL Tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831(v=office.14).aspx) to get your site URL.

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="homelink">
</SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

Notice the URL token of `~site` used in attribute `NavigateUrl="~site/"`. You may have to use the `$SPUrl` command also.

```
<%$SPUrl:~site/myPage.aspx%>
```

You can also refer to this [discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/56bf7cb2-8ca0-4538-9626-68b5bad1d6c0/relative-urls-in-sharepoint-2010-master-pages?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) for more usage examples.

*NOTE: I haven't tried the above examples, but these should be sufficient to provide you a path to your answer.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I got an error using that in my file. "'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 129, position 46."

Comment: @Eddie: What is the code that you wrote? Where did you write the code - SP Designer or Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Designer. Below is : <nav>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="<% $SPUrl:~SitePages/Home.aspx %>">Main</a>
                                </li>

Comment: @Eddie: There is no `~SitePages` URL token in SharePoint. Where did you get that? I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry but will this also work for SP 2013? The links you gave me are mostly for 2010.

Comment: @Eddie: Yes they will. You can verify it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831(v=office.15).aspx They are for 2013

Comment: Thanks again. Will give it a try.

Comment: I managed to add the link by using &lt for < and &gt for > but it doesn't get the site URL. It shows the masterpage URL. I tried it with ~Site and ~SiteCollection.